# Sharepoint How to change function of new document

Tags: function, button, sharepoint, document

I have a document library and whenever I click on the new document (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR8AJ.jpg) it will show  this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/erCJQ.jpg) for me to upload a document. How do I change this, so that it will display this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc2Hd.jpg) instead? I want to create a new document set instead of uploading a document file. Please advise.

I've watch some guides on the internet, their new is at this position. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR8AJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below into script editor web part in list view page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var listTitle="Test600DL";

    var rootFolder=_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/"+listTitle;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')/contenttypes?$select=StringId&$filter=Name eq 'Document Set'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                var contentTypeId=data.d.results[0].StringId;
                var urlString="ContentTypeId="+contentTypeId+"&RootFolder="+rootFolder;
                var $newDocumentLink=$("a[id^='idHomePageNewDocument']");
                $newDocumentLink.attr("onclick",$newDocumentLink.attr("onclick").replace("Upload.aspx","NewDocSet.aspx").replace("RootFolder=",urlString));
                $newDocumentLink.attr("href",$newDocumentLink.attr("href").replace("Upload.aspx","NewDocSet.aspx").replace("RootFolder=",urlString));
            }           
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT, that didn't work. When I click on 'new document' it still prompt me to upload a document instead of creating a document set with template files in place. The only way to create a new document sets is to click on the 'new documents' under files at the ribbon of sharepoint. Please advise

Comment: Did you modify the "listTitle" in the code above? and try to IE F12 debug the code to check if some errors occurs.

Comment: What do I modify the "listTitle" to? I'm not sure if there's an error on edge and IE. But for chrome, it says "fail to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED    jquery.min.js.1". But that doesn't affect the sharepoint right?

Comment: In my test the "listTitle" is "Test600DL", you can try to download the jquery.min.js library and upload it to a document library, then reference it from the document library.